# reStructuredText - How to create table styles used by rst2odt?

Tags: stylesheet, restructuredtext

From the document: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/odt.html#styles-used-by-odtwriter

> The default table style -- Optionally, alter and customize the style applied by default to tables in your document by modifying table "rststyle-table-0" in your stylesheet (styles.odt or a copy). Caution: Do not change the name of this table.

As I understand it, I need to create a table named "rststyle-table-0" and format it the way I want, then save it as styles.odt. The command line to translate rst to odt:

```
rst2odt --stylesheet=styles.odt rst.txt rst.odt
```

This raises an exception:

```
TypeError: cannot serialize None (type NoneType)
Exiting due to error.  Use "--traceback" to diagnose.
Please report errors to <docutils-users@lists.sf.net>.
Include "--traceback" output, Docutils version (0.8.1 [release]),
Python version (2.7.3), your OS type & version, and 
the command line used.
```

Deleting the table "rststyle-table-0", the command works fine.

---

**EDITED:**

First, I found out I did it the wrong way. I should have used a  copy of the file styles.odt (writers/odf_odt/styles.odt in the installation directory) for my custom stylesheet.

Second, the cause of the exception was because my custom table had no border. If you want have a border-less table, you can create a table with white borders.